# Angular Libray build fails with error while pass the params with constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

here is my library service:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

```
export class SharedService {

    name: string;

    constructor(name) { 
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

when i do the build like : `ng build` getting error as :

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for SharedService in C:/722333/Tutorials/my-workspace/projects/ibo-shared-lib/src/lib/services/shared.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for SharedService in C:/722333/Tutorials/my-workspace/projects/ibo-shared-lib/src/lib/services/shared.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
ERROR: Can't resolve all parameters for SharedService in C:/722333/Tutorials/my-workspace/projects/ibo-shared-lib/src/lib/services/shared.service.ts: (?).
```

how to fix this? what is the correct way to handle this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please to look throught https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/377

Comment: Try `constructor(name: string)`?

Comment: @RamilAliyev - there is no solution mentioned there

Comment: @Mridul - no luck

Comment: @user2024080, check [this](https://kendaleiv.com/typescript-constructor-assignment-public-and-private-keywords/) looks similar.

Comment: @Mridul - I have updated as per the article suggestion, but still the issue exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to use @inject in your constructor like below

```
export class SharedService {

name: string;

constructor(@inject('name') name) { 
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

but then you will have to provide a dependency provider with the 'name' in your module as per https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers (useValue / useExisting kind of injection)

Comment: You saved my life. from the morning i was in trouble.